# How to center TabBar horizontally on the TabWidget

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

This is an brief example that would explain what i want:

instead of

```
| TAB 1 | TAB 2 | Tab 3 |XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

i desire

```
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX| TAB 1 | TAB 2 | Tab 3 |XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

note: the number of tabs doesn't change it's fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mac style places the tabs in the center by default, but for the others (Fusion, Windows, etc.) you can set the tab bar alignment in a style sheet.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class Template(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        tab = QTabWidget()
        tab.addTab(QWidget(), 'TAB 1')
        tab.addTab(QWidget(), 'TAB 2')
        tab.addTab(QWidget(), 'TAB 3')
        grid = QGridLayout(self)
        grid.addWidget(tab)
        self.setStyleSheet('''
        QTabWidget::tab-bar {
            alignment: center;
        }''')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle('Fusion')
    window = Template()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Result:

[image]